# nginx not logging any error, no starting

Tags: nginx, logging

After trying to duplicate a nginx to another, I worry about nginx not starting.

`nginx -t` says that the config syntax is ok.

In nginx.conf it's told to log errors: `error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;`

The error.log exists and it is re-created when starting, but always empty.

After `/etc/init.d/nginx start` or `nginx` , there is no notice or error in the shell and also not a line in the error.log. Anyways, `ps -A|grep nginx` tells me that there is nothing started.

Where to find an error message or how to find out what went wrong.

There seems to be no "verbose" mode for nginx :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just type (replace the path to your conf as necessary)

```
nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

And it will print the error to screen.

Comment: that's what i did. this is telling me nothing, no notice, no error or info :-(

Comment: thanks, there was a broken sym link to another version that i did not remove --purge before.

Comment: @ledy did nginx -c show that error or did you find it independently?

Answer (score 0):

For other guys like me:

My problem was on the nginx.pid file. The process was not running, but the file existed, and this prevented to run it. Deleting the file (in my case, /var/run/nginx.pid ), worked.